# Hide spring session bean parameter values in URL

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-mvc, session-variables

Goal: Hide key/value pairs in the URL of a page. E.g. -
http://abc.xyz.com/nav/book?clientID=390&fundID=-1&navDate=-1

I don't want clientID, etc to be visible in URL (security reasons).
I know http is a stateless protocol.

I've tried using HttpSession, Spring @SessionAttributes, and **currently using spring "session" scoped bean**-

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class UserSession {

    private String clientID;
    private String fundID;
    private String navDate;

    public String getClientID() {
        return clientID;
    }
    public void setClientID(String clientID) {
        this.clientID = clientID;
    }
    public String getFundID() {
        return fundID;
    }
    public void setFundID(String fundID) {
        this.fundID = fundID;
    }
    public String getNavDate() {
        return navDate;
    }
    public void setNavDate(String navDate) {
        this.navDate = navDate;
    }
}
```

And use it in **my controller** -

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes(value = {"client","fund","nav"})
public class HomeController {
    @Autowired
    private UserSession userSession;

    @RequestMapping(value = "abc", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView navWorkbook(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            @RequestParam(required = false) String clientID,
            @RequestParam(required = false) String fundID,
            @RequestParam(required = false) String navDate) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("abcd");
        .
        .
        .
        userSession.setClientID(clientID);
        userSession.setFundID(fundID);
        userSession.setNavDate(navDate);
        modelAndView.addObject("userSession", userSession);
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

Is there no way in which I can hide the spring bean's property name/value being shown in the URL ?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In request mapping, you have to use `RequestMethod.POST` instead of `RequestMethod.GET`.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "abc", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, so can you tell me 1.) where this data is stored if not the URL, since http is after all stateless ? 2.) why post differs from get while accessing bean properties ?

Comment: @kaustavdatta The HTTP protocol does not force HTTP servers to read the body of a GET HTTP request. As such request parameters need to be sent in the URL. An HTTP POST however forces the server to read the request body. You can therefore put url-encoded request parameters directly in the body.

Comment: @kaustavdatta but how it works on redirect:value, bcose redirect only works for RequestMethod.GET